# Selecting Menu Items with LibVisca

Tags: camera, video-camera

I have an application that controls cameras. Currently I am adding support for HD cameras using the Visca format. I'm using the LibVisca library to do the low level work. I have successfully added all of the features I need with the exception of the menu system.

I can open the Menu. Move the menu cursor up and down through the list, change settings but I cannot select submenus.

What Visca command do you use to select submenus?  I'm using LibVisca and my camera is a Sony EVi-HD1.

Thanks

Comment: The specs seem to imply that the SetPanTiltHome call should select the submenu when the menu is open. But when I run that command it performs the pan tilt movement rather than opening the submenu

Comment: What calls are you using to Open, Move and Change settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the actual answer Sony took a while to contact me but I got it from the horses mouth.

Visca Protocol has no concept of menus any menus displayed by a camera that uses Visca is hardcoded to only accept menu traversing commands if they come from an InfraRed device ala remote controller.

However Visca has the ability to programmatically change all of these values using Visca.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood, selecting a submenu is achieved by pressing `HOME`.

Did you try sending `Pan-tiltDrive` - `Home` - `8x 01 06 04 FF` to select the submenu?

Comment: Yes this is what I was sending. The Sony rep told me that the model camera I have will interpret this command differently if it comes from the controller rather than from the Visca control port.

Comment: that's what I thought but since you succeeded moving into menus, it could have worked :)

Comment: Yeah, with Cameras that have menus calling the datascreen will open the menu I was moving from PelcoD which needs menus since it's such a limited system. And my bad for accepting my own answer.

Comment: Ok I see. Well about the accepted answer, you obviously got the right answer, I just tried to help. Maybe moderators can do something I don't really know